# Is device memory object address in OpenCL aligned automatically?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, memory-alignment

Here are sample codes:

```
__kernel void my_kernel(__global float* src,
                        __global float* dst){

    float4 a = vload4(0,src);
    //do something to a
    ...
    vstore4(a,0,dst)

}
```

According to [OpenCL 1.2 Reference](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/), address of global buffer `src` and `dst` must be 4-bytes aligned when using `vloadn` and `vstoren`, or the results are undefined. My question is whether OpenCL will automate aligning the global device address after completing the call to `clCreateBuffer`? If not, how to ensure proper alignment?(in addition, how about `local` memory object?)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Data Type of OpenCL](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/dataTypes.html). The OpenCL compiler is responsible for aligning data items to the appropriate alignment as required by the data type. So I think the answer is basically yes.

Answer (score 0):

Buffers are surely aligned to a boundary bigger than 4 bytes, except you are using CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR.

By the way: In your code it could be better to declare the parameters as float4* instead of using vload4 and vstore4.